# Align form elements with no labels in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I align the checkbox with the inputs, without adding a label to it? What's the corret way/best practice in this case?

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/rotavio/pen/GjwLEO

```
<form class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-md-4">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is simply to wrap the checkbox in a div, otherwise yes you can force the checkbox to align but your "remember me" isn't reference.
I would also remove the input from within the label as thats not right, and is inconsistent with what you have above.

```
<form class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="checkbox col-md-4">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
  <div><input type="checkbox">Remember Me</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```